# Cannot create Amazon S3 access policy with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-policies, aws-roles

I'm trying to create the following policy to give full access to Amazon S3 to one of my task definitions (ECS). This is the terraform code I'm using:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "inline_policy_s3" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid       = ""
    actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole", "s3:*"]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["*"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "task_role" {
  name               = "ecs_service_task_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.inline_policy_s3.json
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error when I run `terraform apply`:

```
╷
│ Error: Error creating IAM Role ecs_service_task_role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
│       status code: 400, request id: 25afe8f8-cc66-4533-8f66-9a1f2aeb656b
│ 
│   with module.service.aws_iam_role.task_role,
│   on service/task_role_policy.tf line 16, in resource "aws_iam_role" "task_role":
│   16: resource "aws_iam_role" "task_role" {
│ 
╵
```

I have tried changing some of the attributes of the policy, but I cannot find the problem. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrust policies **don't have** `resources` and **can't have** any other permissions than `sts:AssumeRole`. So it should be:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "inline_policy_s3" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid       = ""
    actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect    = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

For your s3 permissions, you need to create them through, for example, [inline_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#inline_policy).

Comment: Hi, I tried adding my S3 permissions with an inline policy but it does not seem to work, my ECS task cannot access the bucket (getting 403). This is the code https://gist.github.com/antoniogamiz/4cc6f81d488ee811e305e91c0fe8d126 . Do you know what's going on? Should I open another question for that?